# Django url port forwarding

Tags: django, django-urls

I have set up a page in django which currently streams a video from another server on xxxx port.

Everything works fine except that one customer has a firewall and for x reason he can not modify it and the firewall is blocking the port where the video is streamed.

I was wondering if there is any way where i can serve the streaming url as one of my project url.

For example:
The streaming url: http://streamingurl.com:9999/video
My url: http://project.com/video

What i want is with my project to serve the streaming url with my url.

Is this possible with django? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really a Django issue, but here are a number of possible options to pursue:

1. Have your customer contact their network administrator and see if an exception rule can be made for the firewall to allow the streaming video across this particular port from this website.
2. Look into using a web proxy that supports video streaming to get around the firewall rule if it cannot be changed.
3. See if there is an option to embed the video into your website that uses a different port.
4. Contact "streamingurl.com" and see if there is an alternative port that can be used to stream the video - some websites have an alternative even if it is not actively advertised.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, i set up a reverse proxy in my apache configuration and this fixed my problem.

Just for the record, i did the following:
$ sudo a2enmod proxy_http
$ sudo a2enmod proxy

And added to...
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-site
ProxyPass /stream http://www.mysite.com:xxxx/stream
ProxyPassReverse /stream http://www.mysite.com:xxxx/stream